# An alternate proof from Oxtoby's "Measure and Category"

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

From Oxtoby's "Measure and Category" is 
 Theorem 1.1 (Cantor): For any sequence ${(a_n)}$ of real numbers and any interval $I$ there is a point $p \in I$ s.t. $p \neq a_n$ for every n.
I have a different proof than the one provided and I'm wondering if it is valid. 
I went with a simple diagonal slash argument: WOLOG assume the $a_n$ are in $(0,1)$ and likewise $I = (0,1).$ Also suppose the binary representation of all values in question and that they are in a standard representation, for example $1/2$ would be represented as $0.1\bar{0}$ rather than $0.0\bar{1}$. Then define a real number $p$ by setting $p_i=1-a_{ii}$. That is to say, the $i$th digit of $p$ is the boolean complement of the $i$th digit of the $i$th element of the sequence, thereby guaranteeing that $p$ will not be found among the $a_i$. Is this reasoning valid?

Comment: I'd expect to see more justification that you can WOLOG assume $I = (0,1)$.

Comment: Much simpler: $I$ is uncountable.

Comment: @geetha290krm Of course, though that felt like cheating, but yes you're right

Comment: Your argument is missing one point: how would you prove that $p$ does not end by an infinite sequence of of $1$. Since $p$ is defined by $p_i=1-a_{ii}$, why the $p$ would not be, for instance, $0.0\bar{1}$? If this happens, you cannot guarantee that $p$ will not be found among the $a_i$.

Comment: There is a rather simple way to address this point. Assuming $(a_n)$ begins by $a_1$, define the sequence $(b_n)$ by: if $a_n$ is rational then $b_{2n-1}$ is the finite (standard) representation of $a_n$ and $b_{2n}$ is the infinite representation of $a_n$; if $a_n$ is irrational then $b_{2n-1}$ and $b_{2n}$ are both the only representation of $a_n$. Now, define $p$ by $p_i=1-b_{ii}$. Now, you can guarantee that $p$ will not be found among the $a_i$.